# Genymotion Device doesn't run - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, emulation, genymotion

I installed Genymotion and  Genymotion plugin (Android Studio), created a new device and runs properly as shown below :

[genemotion1 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGrOD.png)

but when i click on run button the application doesn't work on Genymotion and appear this message as shown below :

[Genymotion2 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nPof.png)

please can you help me .. and sorry for my language .. thanks in advance .

Comment: Check USB Debugging settings on emulator.

Comment: thanks for your response .. but still not working

Comment: Check these steps, too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825729/how-do-i-connect-flutter-with-genymotion

Comment: thanks i will try it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to connect adb to genymotion device via command prompt.

Comment: thanks for your response .. but how can i do this please ?

Comment: Please tell me how you did it. I am also having the same issue. Thank you.